# How can Matplotlib axes be scaled hyperbolically?

Tags: matplotlib, axes, hyperbolic-function

I have a plot a bit like this:

[image]

The differences between the two lines (red and blue) are most important in my actual data (a ROC curve) at say the grid cell `0.2<x<0.4`, `0.8<y<1`. Now, I could crop for that grid cell, but let's say I'd rather scale both the x and y axes hyperbolically -- where the y-axis hyperbolic curve has its peak at about 0.9 and the x-axis has its peak at about 0.3 -- such that the 2D space gets stretched out for the grid cell of interest and gets compacted elsewhere (and preserving the meaning of the axes tick numbers). How would one accomplish this? The beginnings of my attempt are below. How would my code be modified to implement the axis scaling I described?

```
from   matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import scale as mscale
from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
from   matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter, NullLocator, MultipleLocator
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_palette('husl')
sns.set()
```

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [5, 5]
```

```
x = np.arange(0, 1, step=0.01)
y1 = 1-1/np.exp(10*x)
y2 = 1-1.1/np.exp(10*x)
plt.scatter(x, y1, s=1, facecolor='red')
plt.scatter(x, y2, s=1, facecolor='blue')
plt.show();

class CustomScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
    name = 'custom'
    def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
        mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self)
        self.thresh = None #thresh
        self.name = 'custom'
    def get_transform(self):
        return self.CustomTransform(self.thresh)
    def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
        pass
    class CustomTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True
        def __init__(self, thresh):
            mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)
            self.thresh = thresh
        def transform_non_affine(self, a):
            #return np.log(1+a)
            return np.exp(a)-1
            #return 1+(1/2)*a
mscale.register_scale(CustomScale)

plt.scatter(x, y1, s=1, facecolor='red')
plt.scatter(x, y2, s=1, facecolor='blue')
plt.xscale('custom')
plt.show();
```

Comment: You would still need a inverse function. Did you look at any example? What's the problem?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The goal is to define functions for scaling the axes. I've not seen any examples for doing what I'm trying to do. The problem is that I'm not sure how to proceed from my current code to what I described.

Comment: Consider looking at what happens when you do a logx/y or loglog plot

Comment: Which function do you want to use? (There are two examples in the matplotlib gallery about defining custom scales)

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463431/custom-logarithmic-axis-scaling-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to achieve this using `FuncScale` (registered as `'function'`).

```
f = lambda a: np.exp(a) - 1
g = lambda b: np.log(b + 1)
plt.xscale('function', functions=(f, g))
```

For hyperbolic scaling, you could use `lambda x: 1 / x` for both functions.

See the example in the scales documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/scales/scales.html