# How to enlarge an interval of a matplotlib plot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to build a plot that looks like this:
[image: target plot image]

I care about the x-axis intervals. How do I "zoom" in on a certain interval (here it is 1M - 5M) and then go back to smaller intervals for the rest?
Thanks

Comment: If that's not one of the traditional scales, like log and the like, you're probably going to have to create a custom scale. You need something to transform from and to this scale. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463431/custom-logarithmic-axis-scaling-in-matplotlib

Comment: See also https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale

Comment: Thanks @K.Cl, exactly what I needed